# HP ENVY Photo 7100 only works through HP Smart

Tags: windows-10, printer, network-printer, hp-envy

I have an HP ENVY Photo 7100 series printer. My control panel says that it's offline and I can't print documents the regular way (print queue also says offline), but HP Smart says it's online, and I can print PDFs using "Print Documents" in HP smart. I'm using Windows 10 Home 21H1 build 19043.1348

Answer (score 2):

> HP ENVY Photo 7100 series printer. My control panel says that it's
> offline and I can't print documents the regular way (print queue also
> says offline),

This happens with some HP Printers and some versions of Windows 10. Very up to date Windows versions are better.

Go to Programs and Features and uninstall all HP7100 software (there may be several apps).

Clear the Print Spooler:

> Click Start. Type Command . Right-click “Command Prompt” and select
> “Run as administrator“.
>
> Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“. Type del
> %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers* /Q then press “Enter“. Type net
> start spooler then press “Enter“. The print queue on your Windows
> should now be cleared.

Restart and now use Control Panel, Devices and Printers and Add Printer.  Use the Windows Print Driver.

Once added, connect HP Smart and do a final restart.

All Print functions and Scan via HP Smart should all be working.

You can also try the Windows 10 Drivers on this HP Site:

[HP Drivers for HP 7100 Printer](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-photo-7100-all-in-one-printer-series/9073119)

Comment: there was nothing for the printer in control panel>programs. I did the spooler thing, and removed the printer from control panel and Smart, but now it doesn't show in add a printer

Comment: There are Windows 10 Drivers here from HP and a firmware update as well. Try the drivers on this HP Site.  ... https://support.hp.com/ca-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-envy-photo-7100-all-in-one-printer-series/9073119